# How to Raise Exception to Store Invalid HTML Code to Database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have 2 controls in my asp.net page i.e

1. TextBox Control : this is textmode is multiple
2. Button Control : click to store textbox data into database

Now, i want to store html code to database for that i mention `ValidateRequest="false"` in my `@Page Directive` and also declare in `web.config : <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />`
For Example : 
i want to store this below html code in my database its working great
`<h1> Hello World ! </h1> ----- working`
`<h1> Hello World ! ------- also working, my requirent is i want to raise exception at this point if any tag is not closing their respective tag`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://html-agility-pack.net/outer-html

```
string html = "<span>Hello world</sspan>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

if (doc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
   //Raise Exception here
}
```

Comment: HTMLDocument in which namespace i can find this class

Comment: I have attached a link for this namespace get it from there http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: how to get html agility pack

Comment: In visual studio go to  menu tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console
a window will open enter this command "Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack"

Comment: if i tried to install i'm getting this Error : Install-Package : File contains corrupted data.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], FileFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: is their any other way i can do this

Comment: download it from this link and add a reference to you project http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112471/discussion-between-numan-ali-and-sri).